# ASP.NET Identity Logout and Manage Pages not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I just added Identity to my MVC project and while testing it I found out that I can't log out.
I didn't modify any of the generated files. Just added the _LoginPartial to my _Layout. The login and register links work but when the user is signed in so the links change to manage and logout they both just redirect to login page while the user remains signed in.

This is the code of my _LoginPartial:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using BlogSharp.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark border-0">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

As I said I didn't change anything